# how to get items from database into a well formatted table

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a website that gets items from a database. The way it is at the minute is all items are in the one column. I would like the items to come up in 3 columns and then 3 more under them and so on. Anyone know how to do this?

here is my code

```
<?php
    // Default query for this page:
    $q = "SELECT * FROM item";
    // Create the table head:
    echo '
        <div class="container">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table border="5" class="col-lg-4" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" width="15%"><b>Photo</b></td>
                        <td align="left" width="5%"><b>Condition</b></td>
                    </tr>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    ';

// Display all the items, linked to URLs:
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $directory = '/uploads';
    $file= $row['image_name'];
    // Display each record:
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td align=\"center\"><image src=$directory/$file title='$row[image_name]'  width='213' height='200'></td>
            <td align=\"center\">{$row['state']}</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with PHP, it's all about HTML and CSS.  If you replace your `table` with a series of `div` elements, for example, then you can use CSS to create a variety of fluid layouts for those `div`s.

Comment: how would i format it then so the divs sit where i want them?

Comment: Are you looking to make a table? Also what does the data you get look like? The question is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, you want 3 items per line and you are using the twitter bootstrap css framework.

Your problems comes mainly from the HTML structure you are using.

Try something like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">item 1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">item 2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">item 3</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">item 4</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">item 5</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">item 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your HTML is borked which could be the cause of the display issues.

try removing those 4 closing divs from just above the line marked

// Display all the items, linked to URLs: